# Listview - selection beyond listview borders (no autoscroll when up/down keys)

Tags: vb.net, listview, scroll

Let's say that from 500 items in listview 15 are visible in any time, problem that I'm having is when first/last item **in current view** is reached with up/down keys selection goes beyond listview borders and I can not see what is currently selected.

I know the reason for that is ListView1_KeyDown code, but I had to put up/down key code cause otherwise pressing up or down key from current selection would skip to first item of a listview.

I'll put a few images if I am not explaining this right.

[image][image]
[image]

```
    Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListView1.KeyDown

    On Error Resume Next
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        TextBox3.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        TextBox4.Focus()

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            If ListView1.Items(i).Selected AndAlso i <>
            ListView1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                ListView1.Items(i).Selected = False
                ListView1.Items(i + 1).Selected = True
                ListView1.Focus()
                e.Handled = True

                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            If ListView1.Items(i).Selected AndAlso i <>
            ListView1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                ListView1.Items(i).Selected = False
                ListView1.Items(i - 1).Selected = True
                ListView1.Focus()
                e.Handled = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Tried everything in properties and didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with trial and error.

This fixed it (added line in up key and down key part of the code):

```
ListView1.Items(i).EnsureVisible()
```